# A keylogger that doesn't have to be installed

Tags: windows, gratis, portable, keylogger

We are looking for a free keylogger that should have the main features of the keylogger: [Spytector](https://www.spytector.com/)

The main things we are looking for:

- It should be free.
- It should work like Spytector: The main application allows you to create a "server" which is a small application that is preconfigured. When launched, the application will run stealthily and sends the logs to the main application.
- It should not contain an installation dialogue.
- Should run on any Windows platform.
- Should at least contain logging keystrokes, any other thing (screenshots …) are optional.

It is ok if it was detectable by antiviruses as this is irrelevant (it will be used mainly for demonstration purposes).